“…[it] became a ______ for me.” Why is "gift" the right answer?
This is a cloze test; my focus is on question 28.

People always tell me I was brave to apply to medical school in my 30s. But for me, the bravest thing was to 21 from being a doctor 10 years later.
I’d always wanted to study medicine to help release the world from sufferings but, believing I was not bright enough, I left school at 15 and didn’t return to education until my 30s. 22 the fact that the commute was tough and the money was 23, I kept going this time. I dreamed of becoming a doctor who made a(n) 24.
I spent five years at medical school learning how to fix things, but after graduation, when I worked in a hospital, I soon discovered there were many things in life I was unable to 25. It wasn’t the workload I struggled with, though. What I found really 26 was the emotional load. As a doctor, I knew I would 27 upsetting things. I knew I would watch people die and I knew I would see the most awful things. However, being always present at all these moments became a 28 for me.
I knew I needed a solution to it, and I finally 29 writing. Writing allowed me an escape, a door into another world, and it also helped to 30 my anxieties. Writing, something I had started as a form of treatment, now gave me success, an exit card, and a chance of self-protection. 31 I was wondering whether I was a doctor or a writer. Having thought thick and thin, I 32 my job and took the writing.  It was not a decision I made 33. I knew if I didn’t put myself first, I would eventually disappear.
I still work on the wards now  but as a(an) 34. There are times when you need to focus on yourself. If you have walked so far down a rough road, you may find it 35 to head back because walking away is often the safest route of all.


A. leave B. suffer C. hide D. lean

A. For  B. With C. Given D. Despite

A. sufficient B. tight C. worthless D. missing

A. wish B. decision C. difference D. application

A. handle B. recognize C. choose    D. decide

A  amazing  B. essential C. impossible  D. significant

A. cause B. abandon C. witness  D. fix

A. gift  B. practice C. burden  D. luck

A. turned to    B. gave up  C. run for  D. figured out

A. wipe out B. find out C. hand out D. pick out

A. Recently B. Originally   C. Gradually    D. Apparently

A. quitted  B. regained C. continued    D. led

A. seriously    B. lightly  C. aimlessly D. sadly

A. expert   B. leader C. doctor D. volunteer

A. easy  B. fortunate C. hard D. wise


The standard answer of Question 28 is "gift", but I chose "burden". Could you please tell me which one is the right answer?

What reasoning led you to "burden"? Hint: "awful" (negative) is followed by "however", so we expect something positive or possibly neutral.

@LukeSawczak I would have chosen "burden" as well. The contrast is with the fact that the author knew these things and thought they could handle it. If it was a gift, why would they need a solution? Certain parts of the passage are really not that well written IMO

@the-baby-is-you Right, I guess I'm kind of justifying post hoc here.

It might help to include a few words (or even just a link) explaining what a cloze test is.  (I had to look it up…)

Who or what says that "gift" is the "standard answer"? Maybe you have some mistaken training materials or a teacher is mistaken.

"Gift" is probably the intended answer. It's a substitute for the word "boon" which has a meaning that fits the situation better, but is not as common a word. Just as the answer to 30 would be "alleviate" instead of the given answer.

Is the test quoting something, or writing fiction? If this is a quote, the writer-doctor definitely needs more practice, or else is using a non-standard dialect. If this is fiction, I don't have much confidence in the test setter. A quote at least has the excuse of being a real example

@NoName see my amended answer. This is a bowdlerized version of an article in The Guardian, and the word the author uses is "burden".

@EikePierstorff Ah, the worst of both worlds. Love to see it

Presumably the test suggests it is a "gift" because it provided the narrator with something to write about, which he managed to turn into a new career.

Writing, something I had started as a form of treatment, now gave me
success

I.e. the success is the gift. The narrator would not have started writing without the bad experience.
That is the only way to make sense of the standard answer. I would however agree that the way the text is structured does not really support this, and you can only apply this as an explanation after the fact.
FWIW, in the original text it's actually "burden". The given text is an edited version of Joanna Cannon's article in the Guardian from 2022. The original passage reads

To be present at these vulnerable moments in a stranger’s life is a
privilege, but it also becomes a burden if, like me, you’re unable to
let those moments go.

When I became a doctor, I thought I could cope with the pain and death I would see. I was wrong.
So yes, the test got it wrong.

I believe what happens with a lot of these incorrect tests is that somebody has access to the questions of a standardized test, but not the answers. So they supply their own answers. Quite often, they're incompetent.

Thank you so much Eike, for finding the original article. I doubted myself for a time because of the weird answer, but now I know the right one.

Okay, wow, so they took an original piece that was written correctly by a native English speaker, then paraphrased and rewrote it, introducing a ton of mistakes, and then made that a language test to check the competence of somebody who's just learning the language.  That's just great.

@DarthPseudonym fwiw, I took the trouble of sending a message to Joanna Cannon via the form on her website really out of sheer curiosity to see if she approved of this (although the copyright might be with The Guardian in any case). Copyright questions aside, making a person who makes her living with words seem semi-illiterate might cause them damage (and yes, I know it's probably not relevant to her, but still).

I agree with you that burden makes more sense.
The writer says that they knew they would see distressing things as a doctor - they were prepared for it - however, it was more of a problem than they anticipated. The next paragraph starts I knew I needed a solution (to that problem).

Yes, this is the logical choice. A burden needs a solution, a gift does not.

Burden was the right answer.
In the context, as a native english speaker, I'd have chosen 'burden' as well.

I knew I would watch people die and I knew I would see the most awful things. However, being always present at all these moments became a _____ for me.
I knew I needed a solution to it... Writing allowed me an escape... something I had started as a form of treatment...

The following paragraph is what would clue me in that the blank should be a negative. The "it" there refers back to the blanked out word, and you don't need a solution, escape, and treatment for a gift. You need a them for a burden.
The way I read this is that the doctor is saying "I knew this was going to be tough job when I took it, but even knowing that, the job was wearing me down emotionally, so I started writing as a way to process those feelings."
The use of 'gift' here is not only a poor match for the next paragraph, but feels like a bad pun to me. 'Present' can mean 'in that location' but it can also mean 'a gift', so juxtaposing those words makes it sound like a joke that's quite out of place.
This is a bad test.
That said, assuming this is copied perfectly, this piece of text is full of errors. For example:

...release the world from sufferings but, believing I was not bright enough...

It should say "release the world from suffering" (suffering is a state -- or possibly a mass noun -- not a plural), and the comma should go before the "but" rather than after it.
Similarly, the prase "Having thought thick and thin" is utterly incoherent. The idiom "through thick and thin" means "in good times and bad times" and doesn't make any sense in this context, where the writer apparently meant to say "having thought about it a lot".
I additionally note that the only word that #32 could be that makes sense would be "I quit my job", but the provided word is "quitted", which is not used in modern english.
The poor writing on display here makes me doubt the capabilities of whoever is presenting this as a test. Anyone can make a typo, but this seems like a lot of errors in a short space for what is supposed to be a language test.

native english speaker with a lower case e on English?

@Lambie They said speaker, not writer!

@Peter-ReinstateMonica As we say, still and all...if you can spell the second word in the avatar, you can capitalize the e. Of that I am sure. :)

@Lambie I practically never capitalize language names, whether it's english, french, spanish, latin, or japanese.

@DarthPseudonym - Well, you should when writing in English!

The comma is correct.  "Believing I was not bright enough" is a parenthetical statement which is delimited by commas.  In general though I agree that the text is full of mistakes.

@Lambie: To be fair, Darth's answer doesn't give me any reason to doubt that they are a native English speaker, whereas the text in the original question certainly does.

@TonyK I never said anything at all about this answer not being by a native speaker. That said, we are not Gertrude Stein et alia, so I see no reason not to capitalize English. Maybe  you don't agree. Notice the reaction to Kate's comment.

@neil If it was meant to be a parenthetical (which I disagree with but won't argue here), then it should say "[I wanted to] release the world from suffering, but, believing I was not bright enough, I left school."  There should still be a comma before the but.

+1 Even in the singular, "release the world from suffering" is hardly idiomatic English. Questions 21 and 30 are also not great. I'd consider all of their possible answers to be awkward at best, if not outright incorrect.

Eh, well, "release the world from suffering" has a bit of a buddhist ring to it, so I can't be sure it wasn't intentional, but you're correct about the other questions. In context of the whole piece, I have a feeling 21 expects the answer to be "the bravest thing was to leave from being a doctor" which is just wrong.

I agree with Kate Bunting's answer. In addition, "for" is not usually used as the preposition after "gift" -- we would normally say "a gift to me."
However, the usual preposition used with "burden" is "on". In fact, none of the choices are usually followed by "for".
Mistakes like these are not uncommon in casual language, and will normally be ignored, but they suggest that the quiz was not written by a very good English speaker.

Analysis of possible answers

As a doctor, I knew I would witness upsetting things. I knew I would watch people die and I knew I would see the most awful things. However, being always present at all these moments became a 28 for me.

The passage context is someone who applied to medical school in their 30s, overcame significant challenges, and began a medical career 5 years later. Due to the emotional load they eventually made a difficult choice to leave for their well-being and to pursue writing as a therapeutic escape.
#28, grammar: the unknown word is a noun for the following reasons.

The preceding word a is an article that typically precedes a singular, countable noun. This indicates that the following word must be a noun.
The preceding verb became links the subject to the noun that describes the emotional load — it generally connects to a noun or adjective that describes or identifies the subject.
The sentence structure follows a common pattern of subject + linking verb + noun.

#28, possible choices: (A) gift (B) practice (C) burden (D) luck

Gift implies something positive and beneficial, which doesn’t align with the context of the negative emotional impact described. The author is talking about a heavy emotional load, not something positive. If taken out of context, gift could fit.

Practice is doing something repeatedly to improve skill, which doesn’t fit the context of emotional strain, versus a routine activity.

Burden accurately describes the heavy emotional load the author is carrying from constantly witnessing upsetting events, the toll of the experience.

Luck refers to chance or good fortune, which doesn’t make sense in the negative context. Additionally, luck is a mass noun, meaning it doesn’t typically take an article (a or an) before it — the sentence structure requires a countable noun, which luck is not.


However, the word however (which normally introduces a contrast or contradiction) is in conflict with the overall context and the author likely meant moreover. In such cases of conflict the overall context is generally followed as the author is more likely to be correct in the bulk of the text versus a single instance.
It could be argued that gift is correct in that the negative emotional load pushed the author to become a writer, however, as has been mentioned by @KateBunting, the preposition for is not used with gift in this manner. You can choose a gift for someone, but that is not in the context, rather, giving a gift to someone is. For may be an incorrect word choice by the author, but I would expect an author to be more emphatic about it being a gift, or to say that they eventually saw it as a gift (as it seems obvious to me that they did not consider it a gift at the time).
Thus Burden is the correct choice and the test is wrong (though the text is also wrong, context dictates that the test is more wrong).

Practice is also a noun …the carrying out or exercise of a profession, especially that of a doctor or lawyer. • "he abandoned medical practice for the Church" and […] Group practices also usually have the resources to manage the administrative tasks associated with running a practice, relieving the individual provider from the need to do this alone.…

The standard answer gift (which my original answer supported)
provided by the examiner is incorrect, as explained in the answers and comments from our various contributors here.
Edit (to compare the general interpretation and my previous one)

I knew I would see the most awful things. However, being always present at all these moments became a 28 for me.


I knew I needed a solution to it, and I finally 29 writing. Writing allowed me an escape, a door into another world, and it also helped to 30 my anxieties. Writing, something I had started as a form of treatment, now gave me success, an exit card ...

My summary of the general interpretation from the other answers and the comments
is that the example means despite knowing, despite being armed with knowledge that I would see awful things, these moments still burdened me.  In the paragraph following that, needed a solution further supports this interpretation.
My original interpretation was that despite seeing the awful things, I considered these moments gifts as they spurred me on to go into writing, which subsequently gave me success; these moments were a blessing in disguise. Obviously, from the votes and comments, this is considered incorrect.

This seems to be how the question is intended to be solved, but the writing sample is poorly written.

You are right that "however" introduces an opposite; but the opposite in this case is, I think, that although they knew what was awaiting them it still became an unbearable burden. They went into it clear-eyed but "misunderestimated" (Bush Jr.) the emotional toll it would take. That interpretation is supported by what follows, namely the realization that a solution is needed. If it were a gift one would expect an explanation how it is a gift (e.g. that it makes up for the stress). (Kate said that much, I see.)

To use gift, the positive development later on has to come from the "gift." Instead, the positive development later on came from rejecting the "gift", which shows that it was indeed not a gift at all but actually a burden. The fact that we get to burden in an awkward way is consistent with the other bad writing in this sample.

Thanks to all for your comments.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.  I've now provided this background in my answer.

Can you make this more than just a comment on other answers/comments? As it stands, this really should be deleted as not-an-answer.

Thanks, @Laurel.  I'll add some details tomorrow.

Thanks, @Laurel. I've just added to my answer.

I don't agree with the other answers. The text describes some negative things and then follows with "however" meaning that the word should be positive.
People say a gift doesn't need a solution but it seems to me that the writer is explaining that the negative things needed a solution and then turning to writing was the gift.
